# How insert data to Table * cell * from textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table

I have 3 textboxes, a button "Add", and a table without any data.

I ask the user to enter data on the 3 textbox's and press button "Add". On clicking "Add" I want to insert this data from the textboxes to cell 1 in the table.

How can I do this? I need to fill 3 textbox in one cell not a row.

```
    <h2>Please Enter Car details</h2>

                <asp:Label CssClass="details_label"  ID="lebal1" runat="server" >Owner name</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="details_input" ID="ownerTxt" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Owner name"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:Label CssClass="details_label" ID="label2" runat="server" >Car Brand</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="details_input" ID="brandTxt" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Car Brand"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:Label CssClass="details_label" ID="label3" runat="server" >Car Number</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="details_input" ID="numberTxt" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Car Number"></asp:TextBox>


                <asp:Button CssClass="details_button" ID="addbtn" Text="Add" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="65px"/>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Zone 1</th>
            <th>Zone 2</th>
            <th>Zone 3</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 1</td>
            <td>Cell 2</td>
            <td>Cell 3</td>
        </tr>
</table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Shaharyar
no I use table from tool box

Comment: I know, I am suggesting you to use `GridView` instead. Because after input you will ask how to save it to db or receive in C#. The `GridView` will help you to achieve it all.

Comment: yes I know and I like to use GridView , but this time my leader want to use table :( without datasource

Answer (score 0):

Convert cell 1 to a server control (replace `<td>Cell 1</td>` with `<td id="cell1" runat="server">Cell 1</td>` and so on), add an OnClick handler to `addbtn`, read the values from the textboxes in this handler and assign he values to `cell1`.